# How to select row from table but if it doesn't exist in that table, select from different table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

This may be a really simple problem that I'm over-looking but i have this query:

```
SELECT is_accountant from users where customer_id='cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT'
```

(the customer id will vary, I'm using a node js script to grab a bunch of different customer ids to find out if they're accountants or not)

If there is no result, I want to search in a table called `deleted_users` for the same customer id ie:

```
SELECT is_accountant from deleted_users where customer_id='cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT'
```

Is there a way to do this within Postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT coalesce(u.is_accountant, d.is_accountant)
from deleted_users d
full outer join users u on u.id = d.id
where 'cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT' in (d.customer_id, u.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT is_accountant from users where customer_id='cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT' 

union all

SELECT is_accountant from deleted_users where customer_id='cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT'
and not exists 
(SELECT is_accountant from users where customer_id='cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT')
```

or, as you are interested to know if user "is (or was)" accountant:
(does it matter in which table the user is? Agree?)

```
SELECT is_accountant from users where customer_id='cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT' 
union
SELECT is_accountant from deleted_users where customer_id='cus_4znUZe3lAy26FT'
```